# Asp.NET Page Lifecyle: do Event Handlers run before control Databinding events?

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview, data-binding, web

I am trying to take advantage of the page lifecycle in Asp.NET so that I don't bind to my datasources more than I actually need to.

This has led to the following problem.  I have an ObjectDataSource, GridView, and a button on my page.  The button adds a record to the database, which should be picked up by the data source and presented on the Grid.  The problem is that the item is not showing up on the gridview until I refresh the page.

I can solve the problem by calling GridView.DataBind() in my button's event handler, but this goes against what I understand about the .NET Page Lifecycle.

Based on this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#lifecycle_events), the lifecycle should be as follows:
[image]

In addition the article states that the Databinding event is "Raised after the control's PreRender event, which occurs after the page's PreRender event."

So, my button click event should fire first, during the Event Handling phase.  It should add the record the database.
Next PreRender should be called on the controls.
Finally DataBind should be called on the controls, and the Grid should update to capture the new record.

Yet this doesn't seem to happen.  What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that your viewstate is not enabled on your GridView. This is what I experienced, but then I also had to call DataBind() on the GridView from the page PreRender event if the request was a postback to get the data updated in the GridView on postback.

**Edit:**
It would help to understand the issue and context better if you could post the source code of your page (aspx + codebehind). How and where do you connect your GridView to your datasource? Statically in markup or dynamically? Do you make any calls to page.DataBind()? ... These things may influence the behaviour of the GridView.